# Prove that edge coloring produces a cycle with all edges having the same color

Tags: graph-theory

For a complete graph with vertices $2n+1$ and its edges colored with $n$ colors, how to prove that there exists a cycle with all edges of the same color.

I have proceeded by calculating the number of edges in a complete graph of $2n+1$ vertices which gives $ \binom{2n+1}{2} = n(2n+1) $ edges.

Now using the pigeonhole principle there must be at least $2n+1$ edges of the same color. Now how do I show that this forms a cycle in the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a graph of $2n+1$ edges on $2n+1$ vertices. If this graph has no cycles, it is a tree or a forest. It is know that a tree on $2n+1$ vertices will have $2n$ edges, and a forest will have $2n+1-k$ edges, where $k$ is the number of connected components. Therefore the graph is not a tree or forest, but must contain a cycle.